# An array inside of an array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So here is the thing, I have a json file and inside of that I have an array, and inside of that I have another array.

This is how the json file looks.

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "game": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "price": "5",
            "listofkeys": ["5555w-55w12-2d131","231a1-213x1-31313"]
        },
        {
            "game": "Crusader Kings II",
            "price": "20",
            "listofkeys": ["5555w-55w12-2d131","231a1-213x1-31313"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My questions is, is it possible to do it? Is it possible for me to use this, and then later do something like this:

```
(filename.json).keys.listofkeys.length
```

Is it possible to do .length like that here to check how many arrays there are in "list of keys" ??????
I have tried it for myself, and it does not seem to be working. I need confirmation on this though before I continue. If someone could be so kind to answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: because it is an array you still need to use indexing values. This can easily be checked in the browser itself. Create your page, include the json file, using the dev tools you can set breakpoints on the code or use the console to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.
In your example - the `keys` key is an Array, which mean it doesn't have a `listofkeys` attribute/key.

What you can do is check `keys[0].listofkeys.length` - This will take the first array in the `keys` key of your json-object and on that array - it will take the 
`listofkeys` key and check it's `length`.

Comment: undefined:6
                        "listofkeys": ["5555w-55w12-2d131","231a1-213x1-31313"]
                        ^

Comment: You have a syntax error. You miss a comma after `price": "5"` in your json file. It should be `price": "5", `

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to load an external JSON file by using AJAX and then use the `JSON.parse` method to load that data to a javascript object variable:

**data.json**

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "game": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "price": "5",
            "listofkeys": ["5555w-55w12-2d131","231a1-213x1-31313"]
        },
        {
            "game": "Crusader Kings II",
            "price": "20",
            "listofkeys": ["5555w-55w12-2d131","231a1-213x1-31313"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Javascript to load JSON file**

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
}

function check_json_data(json_data) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(json_data);

    console.log(obj);
    console.log("Keys length:", obj.keys.length);
    console.log("List of keys 1 length:", obj.keys[0].listofkeys.length);
    console.log("List of keys 2 length:", obj.keys[1].listofkeys.length);
}

loadJSON(check_json_data);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

See the console output of my example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/json-load/